# Snakemake: Tranverse DAG depth-first?

Tags: python, snakemake

Snakemake appears to traverse the DAG in a breadth-first manner. Is it possible (e.g. through an option / flag / etc.) to force snakemake to traverse the DAG depth-first?

Comment: How would that be possible to generate a file when the dependences are not generated yet? Overall, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Say I have input files _A_, _B_ and _C_. **Rule 1** generates corresponding files _A_preproc_, _B_preproc_ and _C_preproc_. **Rule 2** generates _A_final_, _B_final_ and _C_final_ using each of the *_preproc files. There are now two option to traverse the resulting DAG: (1) First generate all *_preproc files and then all *_final files OR (2) generate A_preproc, followed by A_final, THEN generate B_preproc and B_final, etc. The first traverse order I would call breadth-first, while the second is rather depth-first. I hope this clears things up :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way I can come up with is by setting priorities for each rule:

```
rule all:
    input:
        ["third_a.txt", "third_b.txt", "third_c.txt"]

rule first:
    output:
        touch("first_{sample}.txt")
    priority: 1

rule second:
    input:
        rules.first.output
    output:
        touch("second_{sample}.txt")
    priority: 2

rule third:
    input:
        rules.second.output
    output:
        touch("third_{sample}.txt")
    priority: 3
```

and if you now run it with `snakemake -j 1` it is executed depth-first!