# Snakemake: Create one target output before moving on to the next in a forked workflow

Tags: snakemake

Imagine you have a workflow with a wildcard (`wc` in the example below) and you want to run it for a large number of different values of that wildcard (e.g. 1000 samples). Typically I would create a `rule all` that takes an input a function that generates the 1000 filenames. But what I've found is that Snakemake will execute `one` 1000 times then `two` 1000 times. This is problematic if the intermediate file produced by `two` is very large, because you end up with 1000 huge files.

Instead, what I would like is for Snakemake to produce `five_1.txt` ... `five_1000.txt`, ensuring that it actually produces one output of `rule all` before moving onto the next. This way, `temp()` deletes one `three_{wc}.txt` before the next is produced and you don't end up with a large number of large files.

In a linear workflow, you can use priorities as suggested by @Maarten-vd-Sande. This is because Snakemake looks at the jobs it can perform, and picks the highest priority, which will always be the one further down the chain in the linear workflow. In a fork however, this doesn't work, because both sides of the fork need to be the same priority, but then Snakemake just does all of one rule first.

```
rule one:
  input: "input_{wc}.txt"
  output: 
    touch("one_{wc}.txt"),
    touch("two_{wc}.txt")
  
rule two:
  input: "one_{wc}.txt"
  output: temp(touch("three_{wc}.txt"))

rule three:
  input: "two_{wc}.txt"
  output: touch("four_{wc}.txt")

rule four:
  input:
    "three_{wc}.txt",
    "four_{wc}.txt"
  output: "five_{wc}.txt"
  shell:
    """
    touch {output}
    """
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snakemake: Tranverse DAG depth-first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173399/snakemake-tranverse-dag-depth-first)

Comment: I just found out that `disk_mb` is a [standard resource](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#standard-resources). You could use that as well to limit the max storage use

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Your solution using priorities would work for the example I gave, so thank you. :) But actually, it doesn't work for my actual workflow because it has a fork in it, whoops. Let me see if I can rewrite this question.

Comment: Not sure if the resources will actually affect the order of rules being executed, will it not just stop anything being executed once the limit is exceeded?

Comment: Never mind, I just make my workflow not a fork but adding a dependency between 2 and 3. It's late :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a fork just make it not a fork. `two` has to execute before `three`. Use @Maarten-vd-Sande's solution.

```
rule one:
  input: "input_{wc}.txt"
  output: 
    touch("one_{wc}.txt"),
    touch("two_{wc}.txt")
  
rule two:
  input: "one_{wc}.txt"
  output: temp(touch("three_{wc}.txt"))
  priority: 1

rule three:
  input: 
    "two_{wc}.txt", 
    "one_{wc}.txt"
  output: touch("four_{wc}.txt")
  priority: 2

rule four:
  input:
    "three_{wc}.txt",
    "four_{wc}.txt"
  output: touch("five_{wc}.txt")
  priority: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Been trying to find a workaround for this for a while.

My problem is that I have initial rules that would produce big temporal files and then later aggregation rules. Either the `greedy` or `ilp` schedulers would run a bunch of disordered initial rules that wouldn't make aggregation efficient and I would run out of disk space. Btw, setting priorities didn't work either.

The best solution I found is batching:

[https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#:~:text=Dealing%20with%20very%20large%20workflows](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#:%7E:text=Dealing%20with%20very%20large%20workflows)

Then I have a script that runs the batches consequently.

My solution is not ideal since until the prior batch is not completely done the next one doesn't start, but it's better than just getting out of disk error.

The right solution should be a flag to indicate depth priority in the scheduler...